# Why does 'strcpy' result in a 'core dumped' error?

Tags: c, ubuntu

```
char **file_update_check(char *sync_file_path, file_Info_t *file_list, char **transfer_file_list)
{
    FILE *sync_file = NULL;
    sync_file = file_open(sync_file_path, "r");

    static char line[512];
    memset(line, 0, sizeof(line));

    int token_count = 0;
    int found = 0;
    int file_list_index;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), sync_file) != NULL)
    {
        char *token = strtok(line, " \n");
        if (token == NULL)
        {
            continue;
        }
        found = 0;
        file_list_index = 0;
        while (file_list[file_list_index].path[0] != '\0')
        {
            if (strcmp(file_list[file_list_index].path, token) != 0)
            {
                file_list_index++;
                continue;
            }

            if (file_list[file_list_index].update_time == file_update_time(token))
            {
                found = 1;
                break;
            }

            file_list_index++;
            break;
        }
        if (found)
        {
            continue;
        }
        transfer_file_list = realloc(transfer_file_list, (token_count + 2) * sizeof(char *));
        // transfer_file_list[token_count] = strdup(token);
        strcpy(transfer_file_list[token_count], token);
        transfer_file_list[token_count][MAX_PATH_LENGTH - 1] = '\0';

        token_count++;
        //transfer_file_list[token_count] = NULL;
    }
```

I tried to copy 'token' to 'transfer_file_list[token_count]' using 'strcpy' in the following code, but it resulted in a 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' error and terminated. I'm not sure what the cause of this issue is. When I use 'strdup' in the commented section, it works correctly, but 'strcpy' or 'strncpy' gives me errors. Please provide a correct code using 'strcpy' or 'strncpy', and if possible, explain the reason behind it.

"transfer_file_list[token_count]" is being assigned the value of "token." "token" contains a string representing a file path.

Comment: You don't check that the reallocation was successful.  The code `oldptr = realloc(oldptr, newsize);` is a recipe for a memory leak when the reallocation fails.  You need to use `void *newptr = realloc(oldptr, newsize); if (newptr == NULL) { …handle allocation failure… } oldptr = newptr;` instead.

Comment: The `memset(line, 0, sizeof(line));` call is unnecessary.

Comment: Your `strcpy()` line is copying to an uninitialized pointer.  You need to use `transfer_file_lis[token_count] = strdup(token);` or equivalent to allocate space for the token as well as record that you've found the token.  You need the `realloc()` too.

Answer (score 1):

You did not put the effort to make a MCVE. If you did, you would notice that the following lines are enough to reproduce the issue,

```
        transfer_file_list = realloc(transfer_file_list, (token_count + 2) * sizeof(char *));
        // transfer_file_list[token_count] = strdup(token);
        strcpy(transfer_file_list[token_count], token);
```

When you use `strdup` as in your commented code, the standard library allocates a new buffer for you and copies `token` into it, and returns the pointer to the buffer to you, which you can save for later use.

This is not the case if you use `strcpy` in the way as you do. You have to allocate the buffer yourself and then copy to it. As written, you are only performing allocation for the `transfer_file_list` `char*` array, but after the allocation, `transfer_file_list[token_count]` is uninitialized and therefore holds indeterminate value. Using the indeterminate value in `stdcpy` results in undefined behavior.

The correct way is to allocate the buffer to hold the string,

```
        char** newptr = realloc(transfer_file_list, (token_count + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        if(!newptr){
            //handle error
            return NULL;
        }
        transfer_file_list = newptr;
        transfer_file_list[token_count] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
        if(!transfer_file_list[token_count]){
            //handle error
            return NULL;
        }
        strcpy(transfer_file_list[token_count], token);
```

Note that you should never overwrite the initial pointer in case of `realloc`, that is, `ptr = realloc(ptr, ...)` is always wrong. This is because if the allocation failed, you need to free the original `ptr` somehow to prevent memory leak, but if you use `ptr = realloc(ptr, ...)` you no longer have access to the original pointer.

I also cannot see why you need to allocate `token_count+2`. I never see you need to use the index `token_count+1`, so allocating for `token_count+1` should be enough.

Also note that you are using `char **transfer_file_list` as the parameter and the new `transfer_file_list` value will not be seen by the caller from the parameter. Make sure you return the new `transfer_file_list` value to the caller.

The line `transfer_file_list[token_count][MAX_PATH_LENGTH - 1] = '\0';` is also wrong. Firstly you never need to explicitly assign the NUL character when using `strcpy`, it is always handled automatically. Secondly there is no guarantee that the buffer length is as long as `MAX_PATH_LENGTH` and you are very likely writing to an out-of-bound address of `transfer_file_list[token_count]`. If this line is present, the code has undefined behavior even if you use `strdup`.

Finally, for `strncpy`, the corresponding code should be

```
        char** newptr = realloc(transfer_file_list, (token_count + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        if(!newptr){
            //handle error
            return NULL;
        }
        transfer_file_list = newptr;
        size_t token_len = strlen(token);
        transfer_file_list[token_count] = malloc(token_len+1);
        if(!transfer_file_list[token_count]){
            //handle error
            return NULL;
        }
        strncpy(transfer_file_list[token_count], token, token_len+1);
```